# why predict a distribution in pixelcnn++

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision, generative-models

I know that in the original pixelcnn paper, they predicted a 255 vector for each subpixel, and argmaxed to get the value.
in the pixelcnn++ paper, if I understand it correctly, they model the pixel value as a mixture of logistic distributions.
I understand why the mixture approach is better than a 255 vector - but why not just predict a single value- the value of the pixel. you can scale all the images to range (0,1) and use a sigmoid activation, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pixelcnn (and autoregressive density models in general) define the distribution $p(X) = \prod_i p(x_i | x_{<i}; \theta)$ where each term $p(x_i | x_{<i}; \theta)$ is defined by some neural network -- in this particular case, a CNN model.

> why not just predict a single value

The goal is not to predict the value of the next pixel, the goal is to define and learn a distribution on the space of images. To make it clear why it doesn't make sense to predict a single value... imagine there are just two images in your dataset, each one is 2 by 2 greyscale, and the values are as below.

Image 1:

```
1 2
2 0
```

Image 2:

```
1 2
2 4
```

Suppose your autoregressive model has seen the first three pixels and now must predict the value of the last bottom right pixel. There is no "single value" which is correct here.